# vaadin runWhileAttached method

Tags: java, runnable, vaadin7, vaadin-charts

How do you implement the runWhileAttached method, like in this demo:

http://demo.vaadin.com/charts/#SplineUpdatingEachSecond?

```
runWhileAttached(chart, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final long x = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final double y = random.nextDouble();
            series.add(new DataSeriesItem(x, y), true, true);
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
```

Receive error: method runWhileAttached is undefined for type myApp.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the implementation for that: https://github.com/vaadin/charts/blob/7a55e8dab5b9941a05603c2624a576866e86045d/examples/src/main/java/com/vaadin/addon/charts/examples/AbstractVaadinChartExample.java#L29

It summary it puts polling with 1 second intervals, starts a new thread and while the UI still exists (=component is attached to UI), it runs the task and waits for one second.